# How to completely remove Python 2 and install Python 3?

Tags: python

In Loki when I type python --version i get 2.7.

I want to remove Python 2.7 kompletely and install instead Python 3 how to do that?

Comment: please don't do that, most of ñinux packages uses python2 for installing things, removing it will cause several problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen that done before (2.7 replacing 2.4) and things didn't go really well. As @Renato A. has mentioned, lots of Linux packages uses Python 2. You can check the files on `/bin` or `/usr/bin` and see that some of them are actually just Python scripts or in some manner pointing to one.

It's not obvious but scripts that are made for Python 2 won't necessarily work on Python 3. Python 3 intentionally has no backwards compatibility.

You can always install Python 3 alongside with Python 2 and just call `python3` instead of `python` whenever you need it.

Comment: I just got some problems with Python2 and Python3 globally. I tried to install sphinx and got error. Now I use virtualenv and everything is ok.

I thouth that Ubuntu 16.04 switched to python3 by default but it doesn't seem so.

Comment: virtualenv is the way to go. I don't think we'll get Python3 as default on the next few Ubuntu releases as they are completely dependent on the individual developers' decision to migrate to Python3.